# Get index position value in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm confused on why in the following two code blocks, printing the `$arr` gives the same output but `$arr['type'][0]` does not. Notice the `r` in the 2nd code block output:

```
$arr=array('type'=>' review');   
print_r($arr);
echo '<br>';
print_r($arr['type'][0]);
```

---

```
$arr['type']='review';   
print_r($arr);
echo '<br>';
print_r($arr['type'][0]);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [type] => review )
```

---

```
Array ( [type] => review ) 
r
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra space:

```
$arr=array('type'=>' review');   
                    ^-- right there
```

I think it's printing the space, which you don't see because HTML is whitespace insensitive.

It's also possible PHP throws a warning. Indexing a string like it's an array is usually a bug. Make sure you've got errors and notices turned on.

Comment: omg that is just stupid on my part. I thought there was something much higher level going on. Thanks!

Comment: I hate it when that happens... we have all done it if we have been at it long enough.

Answer (score 2):

In your first code block, `$arr=array('type'=>' review');` there is a space between the first single quote and the r in review.  That is why your first code block appears to print nothing, since it is printing out a space character.

Change that code to `$arr=array('type'=>'review');` to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it does the same thing. Notice the space you have in the first block:

```
$arr = array('type' => ' review');
// ---------------------^
print_r($arr);
echo '<br>';
print_r($arr['type'][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

print_r prints the information on the array. The array you are passing print_r is an array of characters, which is all a string is. [0] shows 'r', [1] shows 'e', and so on. This is why print_r($arr['type']) shows the full string and adding the second index shows the appropriate character at whatever index you provide.